# ProtectSection force save

Tags: c#, .net, integration-testing

How to force the following code to be hit by the test below?

```
if (!section.SectionInformation.IsProtected)
{
     section.SectionInformation.ProtectSection(encryptionProvider);
}
```

The problem is that other tests call Encrypt before the test below, so the code never gets inside the statement above.

So far the force saving in the test does not seem to do anything.

```
[TestCategory("Integration"), TestMethod]
public void TestProtectSectionOnlyHappensOnce() // integration test
{
    // Arrange
    IAppConfigEncryptor encryptor = new AppConfigEncryptor();
    bool expected = false;
    bool actual;

    // Act
    try
    {
        Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
        var section = config.GetSection("appSettings");
        section.SectionInformation.SetRawXml("");
        config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Full, true);

        encryptor.Encrypt("appSettings", "DataProtectionConfigurationProvider");
        encryptor.Encrypt("appSettings", "DataProtectionConfigurationProvider");
        actual = false;
    }
    catch (NullReferenceException)
    {
        actual = true;
    }

    // Assert
    Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use the separate configuration file so that tests will not interfere. Thanks to that all tests will be independent.

1. There is a method [OpenMappedExeConfiguration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/ms134269%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which will allow you to open a non-default configuration file.
2. You can add a second configuration file to your project and use [DeploymentItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.deploymentitemattribute.aspx) attribute to automatically copy it to the test directory.